# Is there a way I can set the TTL (time to live) as an argument when compiling this small ping application

Tags: c, ping, icmp, icmpsendecho2

I am building a small application for the ICMP protocol (ping) using Echo request and reply. The Time to live (TTL) is set by default to the receiver's TTL and I was wondering if I can get help in setting a custom TTL as an argument when compiling the code. Thank you in advance for your valuable help.

TO COMPILE:

gcc -o MyPing file_name.c

sudo ./myping www.google.com

Code starts here:

> Blockquote

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <stdio.h>

#include <string.h>

#include <netdb.h>

#include <unistd.h>

#include <signal.h>

#include <sys/socket.h>

#include <sys/time.h>

#include <arpa/inet.h>

#include <netinet/ip.h>

#include <netinet/ip_icmp.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024

#define ICMP_HEADER_LENGTH 8

#define DATA_LENGTH (64 - ICMP_HEADER_LENGTH)

int msg_count;

int msg_received_count;

int seq = 0;

pid_t pid;

int sock;

struct addrinfo *host;

int get_addrinfo_v4(const char *host, struct addrinfo **result) {

struct addrinfo hints;



memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));

hints.ai_family = AF_INET;

hints.ai_flags = AI_CANONNAME;



return getaddrinfo(host, NULL, &hints, result);

}

const char *get_sockaddr_text(

const struct sockaddr *address,

char *text, socklen_t text_length

) {

return inet_ntop(

   address->sa_family,

   &(((struct sockaddr_in *)address)->sin_addr),

   text,

   text_length

   );

}

double timeval_to_ms(const struct timeval *time) {

return (time->tv_sec * 1000.0) + (time->tv_usec / 1000.0);

}

u_short checksum(u_short *data, int length) {

register int data_left = length;

register u_short *p = data;

register int sum = 0;

u_short answer = 0;



while (data_left > 1) {

sum += *p;

p++;

data_left -= 2;

}



if (data_left == 1) {

*(u_char *)(&answer) = *(u_char *)p;

sum += answer;

}



sum = (sum >> 16) + (sum & 0xffff);

sum += (sum >> 16);

answer = ~sum;

return answer;

}

void alarm_handler(int signal_number) {

int icmp_packet_length = DATA_LENGTH + ICMP_HEADER_LENGTH;



char send_buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];

memset(send_buffer + ICMP_HEADER_LENGTH, 0, DATA_LENGTH);



struct icmp *icmp_packet = (struct icmp *)send_buffer;

icmp_packet->icmp_type = ICMP_ECHO;

icmp_packet->icmp_code = 0;

icmp_packet->icmp_id = pid;

icmp_packet->icmp_seq = seq++;

gettimeofday((struct timeval *)icmp_packet->icmp_data, NULL);

icmp_packet->icmp_cksum = 0;

icmp_packet->icmp_cksum = checksum((u_short *)icmp_packet, icmp_packet_length);



sendto(sock, send_buffer, icmp_packet_length, 0, host->ai_addr, host->ai_addrlen);



alarm(1);

msg_count++;

}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

if (argc != 2) {

printf("usage: %s host\n", argv[0]);

exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

}



pid = getpid() & 0xffff;



int status = get_addrinfo_v4(argv[1], &host);

if (status != 0) {

printf("error: %s\n", gai_strerror(status));

exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

}



sock = socket(host->ai_family, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_ICMP);

if (sock < 0) {

perror("socket");

exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

}



setuid(getuid());



struct sigaction action;

action.sa_handler = alarm_handler;

if (sigaction(SIGALRM, &action, NULL) < 0) {

perror("signal");

exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

}



char send_ip[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];

get_sockaddr_text(host->ai_addr, send_ip, sizeof(send_ip));



printf(

   "PING %s (%s): %d data bytes\n",

   host->ai_canonname,

   send_ip,

   DATA_LENGTH

   );



alarm_handler(SIGALRM);



char receive_buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];

struct sockaddr receive_address;

char control_buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];



struct iovec iov;

iov.iov_base = receive_buffer;

iov.iov_len = sizeof(receive_buffer);



struct msghdr msg;

msg.msg_name = &receive_address;

msg.msg_namelen = sizeof(receive_address);

msg.msg_iov = &iov;

msg.msg_iovlen = 1;

msg.msg_control = control_buffer;

msg.msg_controllen = sizeof(control_buffer);



struct timeval receive_time;

char receive_ip[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];



for ( ; ; ) {

ssize_t n = recvmsg(sock, &msg, 0);



if (n > 0) {

struct ip *ip_packet = (struct ip *)receive_buffer;

if (ip_packet->ip_p == IPPROTO_ICMP) {

int ip_header_length = ip_packet->ip_hl << 2;

int icmp_packet_length = n - ip_header_length;

if (icmp_packet_length >= 16) {

struct icmp *icmp_packet = (struct icmp *)(receive_buffer + ip_header_length);

if (

icmp_packet->icmp_type == ICMP_ECHOREPLY &&

icmp_packet->icmp_id == pid

) {

gettimeofday(&receive_time, NULL);

struct timeval *send_time = (struct timeval *)icmp_packet->icmp_data;

msg_received_count++;

printf(

   "%d bytes from %s: icmp_seq=%u ttl=%d time=%.3f ms\n",

   icmp_packet_length,

   get_sockaddr_text(&receive_address, receive_ip, sizeof(receive_ip)),

   icmp_packet->icmp_seq,

   ip_packet->ip_ttl,

   timeval_to_ms(&receive_time) - timeval_to_ms(send_time) );







}



printf("\n%d packets sent, %d packets received, %f percent packet loss. \n\n",

   msg_count, msg_received_count, ((msg_count - msg_received_count)/msg_count) * 100.0);

}

}

}

}



return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}
```

Comment: Please improve the code formatting (type gg=G on vim) and remove the extra lines

Answer (score 0):

Tl;dr

[`setsockopt()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setsockopt.3p.html) can be used to set a different TTL value on your ICMP socket.

For example:

```
/* sets TTL to 100 */
setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_ICMP, IP_TTL, &(int){100}, sizeof(int));
```